# IzPack install required JDK/JRE version from installer

Tags: java, izpack

I am new to IzPack and trying to create a jar installer packaging for one of my application.

In IzPack there is provision that we can define min & max version of the JDK to use for the application. And if the required java version is not found then JDKPathPanel will get used to set the path.
But this panel requires user to provide the JDK path manually.

I don't want such manual input to be used. Instead I want to install the JDK/JRE version I will be providing with my application.

There are some ways like ProcessPanel & executable tag in pack. But I don't know how exactly use them in my condition. And also there are very limited resources about the IzPack.

So someone please help me out for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Yogesh,is the question answered by anyone in offline. I am facing the same issue.Exception what i am getting is                                                                                            install.xml:3: the file version is different from the compiler version. My java version is 1.8.0.11 . I think izpack uses by default jdk 7. How this can be solved